# Django-Filebrowser and uploading images

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli, django-filebrowser

I have Django Grappelli == 2.6.5 with Filebrowser and Tinymce. I use Django ==1.7.5.
I have problem with uploading images. Image uploads in the browser, appears in the folder *\media\uploads* but Filebrowser doesn't see it and throws an error: **'media\uploads\img.jpg' could not be found**
Here is my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))
MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, *MEDIA_URL.strip("/").split("/"))
DIRECTORY = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY", 'uploads/')
```

In the pyhon shell I did following:

```
from django.conf import settings 
import filebrowser.settings
filebrowser.settings.MEDIA_ROOT
C:\\mysite\\static\\media
filebrowser.settings.DIRECTORY
uploads/
```

Why is this happened? How can I set the right upload directory to Django-Filebrowser? I've read documentation and searched for answears in google. But I don't understand how fix it and I'm confused. Can you help me please.

Comment: does media\uploads\img.jpg have a file size?

Comment: Yes, 176 kb as original image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your projects urls.py:

```
from django import views
....


urlpatterns = [

...

url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', views.static.serve, {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})
...

]
```